# Pros/Cons of Deploying Ruby on Rails Project Subversion Working Copy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, automation, deployment

A couple of the Rails projects on which I'm working appreciate frequent, incremental updates, which I think is great.  Our current deployment strategy is manual but we're considering switching to an automated tool like Capistrano; however, it also occurred to me that it might be even better to just deploy a Subversion working copy instead.

Here are the benefits I can see, off the top of my head:

1. No need to export/zip/copy/ssh/unzip to deploy code (just `svn update`).
2. Easily rollback to any revision (e.g. `svn update -r 123`).
3. Easily determine currently deployed revision (`svn info` / `svn diff`).

Of course, this strategy wouldn't be appropriate for large institutions that have environment controls and separation, but aside from that, what are some of the drawbacks to this strategy versus a formal automated deployment tool?

Answer (score 0):

What happens when someone commits a quick broken change or commits with debugging still left on?

You're better off tagging commits as "production" or something similar if you want a commit deployed. Then have a deploy script that periodically checks for a new production release, strips out any debug files/options, and puts the files in the right place.